# Pacakge Version Conflict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipe, spyder

When I tried to run the code, I found the following error whereas package already installed in the system.

Tool used for it spyder with anaconda 3.5 version

> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.5.egg\pkg_resources__init__.py",
>   line 859, in resolve
>       raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
>
> ContextualVersionConflict: (Pillow 3.3.1 (c:\program
>   files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages),
>   Requirement.parse('Pillow>=4.0.0'), {'ocrmypdf'})

Comment: Are you using virtual environments to isolate your dependencies and versions from other projects in your computer?